# Converting HTML Code to Image File

Tags: python, html, python-imaging-library

I've been searching and the only thing that i can find to convert an HTML image to .jpg, .gif, or any other is by taking screen shots. (or other ways, but always through the output)

What i would like is to make it internal, for example, i have a chart code of a Google chart:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["geochart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

      function drawRegionsMap() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Country', 'Popularity'],
          ['Germany', 200],
          ['United States', 300],
          ['Brazil', 400],
          ['Canada', 500],
          ['France', 600],
          ['RU', 700]
        ]);

        var options = {};

        var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="regions_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

So, my question is, is it possible to convert this code to an image using Python ?

Answer (score 3):

Possible approaches:

Spawn a **Browser**, load html, let it render, take a screenshot. You can use a headless browser (https://github.com/brenden/node-webshot) or an almost browser in a headless X server (https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyWebkitGtk), or a real browser.

Use **Javascript** to do the same (https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) which still requires your Javascript to run somewhere, whether node.js or command line or headless or real browser.

Ask Google Charts for an **image file** instead of drawing on canvas (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/printing). YMMV, and that depends on what Google offers. You may use some other charting library.